# css columns , the right way to implement?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I wanted to implement the design below , but I am having trouble on the positions , can anyone give a basic css example and implementation of the sample image below ? Help would really be appreciated. Thank you. are we going to use col for that ? how do we seperate text based on the design ?

[image]

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: My implementation is complex Sir , you may not understand it , but can you please provide a basic example of the implementation ? never mind the image , just use icons Sir

Comment: @Armin can you show me a basic example Sir ?

Comment: Hmmm...multi-accounting much? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967295/html-and-css-how-to-arrange-items-inside-a-col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple example using `bootstrap`:

```css
.col {
  background-color: red;
}

#icon {
  background-color: green;
}

hr {
  border-top-width: 3px !important;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col m-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="icon" class="col-4">
        ICON
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <h3>
          Unmuted
          <span class="arrow-up"></span>
        </h3>
        <hr>
        <p>
          Panacast
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col m-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="icon" class="col-4">
        ICON
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <h3>
          Unmuted
          <span class="arrow-up"></span>
        </h3>
        <hr>
        <p>
          Panacast
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: , how about the line sir ? and the other icon which is the green triagle icon ? how about its position ?

Comment: the gray line below Un muted

Comment: I think [johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583669/johannchopin) gave you a basic example of css as you asked. But the way you asking is like you don't know anything about css, are you?

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin Well how about to `upvote` first my answer ? ;)

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin Make an update to add an example of line separate (`hr`) and a triangle. I have not the time to do better ;)